# Css grid and image overlay

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have tried putting the hover effect on an image within a css grid but just can not get the placement right. The problem occurs when rolling over the image.

The hover effect shows up above the grid. I want the hover to occur over the appropriate image. I have looked at hundreds of posts but for some reason, I can not see the problem. I have tried to solve this using just CSS, and would like to have it solved with using just CSS, but I am open to suggestions.

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong? Any help you can provide would be most appreciated.  Thanks for your help!

I have provided a link to my codepen:
https://codepen.io/sktorres/pen/NoBZQV

Below is the CSS that I have coded along with my main wrapper that holds the grid:

```css
    .wrapper{
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto;
      grid-template-rows: auto 30% 40% auto auto;
      grid-template-areas:
      "hd"
      "hero  "
      "casestudies"
      "contact"
      "ft";
    }
    /* case studies */
    .casestudies {
      align-items: stretch;
      display:grid;
      grid-area: casestudies;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto;
      justify-self: stretch;
      margin:0;
    }
    .work{
     background-color:#F4FAFF;
      grid-column: span 3;
     height: auto;
      padding: 1rem;
      margin:0;
    }
    .work h2{
     color: #333745;
     font-size: 3rem;
     font-weight:300;
     text-align: center;
    }

    .content .content-overlay {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

    .content:hover .content-overlay{
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .content-image{
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
    }
    .content-details {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 1rem;
      width: 100%;
      top: 40%;
      left: 50%;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

    .content:hover .content-details{
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .content-details h2{
      color: #F4FAFF;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    .content-details p{
      color: #F4FAFF;
      font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .fadeIn-bottom{
      top: 80%;
    }

And this is the html to call up my CSS:
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">     
    <!-- Work -->
    <div class="work">
    <h2>Case Studies</h2>
    </div>
    <section id="casestudies" class="casestudies">
    <article class="content">
    <a href="autoshow.html">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362" alt="" />
    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
    <h2 class="content-title">kbb.com</h2>
    <p class="content-text">New Car Tablet Experience</p>
    </div>
    </a>
    </article>

    <article class="content">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362" alt="" />
    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
    <h2 class"content-title">National Association of Realtors</h2>
    <p class="content-text">Onboarding Project</p>
    </div>
    </article>

    <article class="content">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362" alt="" />
    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
    <h2 class"content-title">GWR Smart Home</h2>
    <p class="content-text">Mobile App</p>
    </div>
    </article>

    <article class="content">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362" alt="" />
    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
    <h2 class"content-title">kbb.com</h2>
    <p class="content-text">Trade In Value</p>
    </div>
    </article>

    <article class="content">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362" alt="" />
     <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
    <h2 class"content-title">kbb.com</h2>
    <p class="content-text">Website Redesign</p>
    </div>
    </article>

    <article class="content">
    <div class="content-overlay"></div>
    <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362" alt="" />
    <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
    <h2 class"content-title">TCP Lighting</h2>
    <p class="content-text">Smart Lighting Mobile App</p>
    </div>
    </article>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you need to do is to set the position of the wrapping container to relative. Has nothing to do with the grid, it is just the positioned element is relative to body and calculates width, height and position to body instead of its parent.

You draw the background to

```
.content .content-overlay
```

Set the parent container to relative and it works.

```
.content {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to have the animation come up as the size of the entire viewport. This was a bit tricky, but if you inspect the console, you can see that the animation attempts to come up as the entire screen. If you change the position of the content class to be relative, this will make the animation only pop up on the element you want.